# jquery context menu plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the context menu plugin, it works, but everytime an ajax load event starts the effect of the context menu isn't showing, the menue no more is valid.

```
  $("").contextMenu({
        menu: 'myMenu'
    },
        function(action, el, pos) {
      switch (action) {
            case "option":
                {

                  $.post("", {}, function() {

                            $().load();


                            });

                            break;
                }
        }
    });
```

Here is te menue code, and when the load in the ajax post start the menue dissapear.

Comment: Any code or something you would like to share? A http://jsfiddle.net exemplifying your issue would be perfect.

Comment: I edited the question, if u tell me how to give an example with ajax.. i will give you one

Answer (score 0):

You still left out a lot of details (which plugin source-file), how is the html you bind it to and so on. Nonetheless here are my pointers:

- often plugins are bound to elements on document ready
- if you load additional elements via ajax these elements were not present during document ready

You can do the following
 - rebind the elements after the ajax has loaded; you can use the callback function of the ajax